# Let $R$ be the ring of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $(0, 1)$ and and prove that $I=\{f∈R:f (1/3)=0\}$ is a maximal ideal in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be the ring of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $(0, 1)$ and $I=\{f∈R:f (1/3)=0\}$. Prove that is a maximal ideal in $R$.

I am honestly lost here, i have studied abour ideals in rings in general, but i still am not very much Familiar with the maximal ideals in abstract algebra, except that to prove if I is a maximal ideal meaning its the largest proper subset of a ring, i need to show there is other ideal larger than I that contains I then ita no other than the ring itself , that's the definition i understood, but i cant seem to apply it on this question,maybe i am doing it wrong. A detailed proof would really help me out to understand more. Thank you

Comment: @saad i don't have MathJax, neither do o know how to use it, but i did correct the form of the question. I hope now its understandable?!

Comment: A maximal ideal is not "*the largest* proper *subset*" of a ring: it's *a maximal* proper *ideal*, which is a proper ideal $\mathfrak m$ such that, for all proper ideals $I$, either $\mathfrak m\nsubseteq I$ or $I=\mathfrak m$; equivalently, such that if $I$ is an ideal and $I\supsetneq \mathfrak m$, then $I$ is the whole ring.

Comment: See [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Comment: @Gae.S i hace only worked on one definition of maximal ideals, so allow me.to proceed with that. Let me take an ideal B of ring that contains I but doesn't equal it, so i need to show B=R. Now since I is a proper subset of B , then there must exist a function g in B such that g(1/3) doesn't equal 0. If i were able to prove that B contains a constant function which is a unit of Real valued continuous functions than i can directly say B=R ( by exercise 15 in contemporary abstract algebra 8th edition ).

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be an ideal of $R$ properly containing   $I$ ($N\neq I$). Then there exists $f\in N$ but not in $I.$ This means $f(1/3)\neq 0$ and say$f(1/3)=c\neq 0.$ Let $g\in R$ by $g(x)=c, x\in(0,1).$ Consider $h\in R$ such that $h=f-g.$ But then $h(1/3)=0$ and hence  $h\in I\subset N.$ Then   $f-h=g\in N$. Now define $i(x)=1/c, x\in(0,1). $ But then  $i(x)\in R$ and hence $ig\in N.$
Observe that $i(x)g(x)=1$ for all $x\in(0,1).$ Thus unity element of $R$ is in $N$ and hence $N=R.$

The proving of I  is an ideal of R, is left to you. Complete it.

Comment: OK thanks alot, i will prove the left part !!

Comment: How did u make sure that h(1/3)=0 ???

Comment: $h(1/3)=f(1/3)-g(1/3)=c-c=0.$